# Compute the integral of $\exp{(-x^2 - a(x-by)^2)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

After some computations on a probability problem, I find myself in front of
$\int \int \exp{(-x^2 - a(x-by)^2)}dx dy$

(integration over $\mathbb{R}^2$)
I have no ideas how to compute that... Does someone has an idea?

Comment: Is it $$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \exp{(-x^2 - a(x-by)^2)}\,dx\,dy $$

Answer (score 3):

Let $u=x,v=\sqrt a(by-x)$ and the integral becomes

$$\frac1{\sqrt a\,b}\iint e^{-u^2-v^2}du\,dv=\frac1{\sqrt a\,b}\int e^{-u^2}du\int e^{-v^2}dv.$$

(The constant is the Jacobian of the linear transform.)

Comment: thank you for your answer, that is helpful